# PHP IF ELSE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following statement in my page and it doesnt seem to be processing, Can anybody see any obvious errors which im missing?

```
else{
    if($usersClass->register($_POST['produgg_username'], md5($_POST['produgg_password']), $_POST['produgg_email'], $randomkey)) 
    {
        print "success";
        $toemail = $_POST['produgg_email'];
        $touser = $_POST['produgg_username'];
        // Send activation email 
         $to = $toemail;
         $subject = "Activation";
         $headers = "From: support@.co.uk";
         $body = "Howdy $touser!";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        if(isset($_POST['r']) {
                        $refcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r']);
                        mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET credits=credits+200000 where produgg_users.id = ".$refcode or die(mysql_error());

                        };


    }else{
        print "error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like me to flip a coin over what `$usersClass->register()` actually returns?

Comment: The code is cutted on top. You need to show the whole - incl. the outer - if statement(s), otherwise I would say that else is never called (the outer one).

Answer (score 1):

This line will error out:

```
 mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET credits=credits+200000 where produgg_users.id = ".$refcode or die(mysql_error());
```

Should be something like

```
mysql_query(
  "UPDATE produgg_users SET credits=credits+200000 where produgg_users.id = ".$refcode) 
   or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your isset function is missing the closing parenthesis

```
if( isset($_POST['r']) ) {
    $refcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r']);
    mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET credits=credits+200000 where produgg_users.id =    ".$refcode or die(mysql_error());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `$usersClass->register()` returns it's difficult to make a determination over what is going wrong. I do advise you try something like the following (just for debugging purposes):

```
var_dump($_POST);
$_test = $usersClass->register($_POST['produgg_username'], md5($_POST['produgg_password']), $_POST['produgg_email'], $randomkey);
var_dump($_test);
// proceed on with your if statement.
```

Make sure you're seeing what you expect to see. A few echo's in developement code never hurt anyone, just make sure they're removed for release purposes.